# Unable to connect to device across subnet

Tags: networking, ping, subnet

I have a network printer (Sharp copier) that I am unable to contact from a different subnet . I am on 192.168.100.x. The printer is on 192.168.200.x. I can ping (or remotely connect to) every other device (including switches, desktops, server)  on the '200' subnet from the '100' subnet. I have an identical copier on the '200' subnet that I can connect to.

If I am on the '200' subnet, I can contact the printer without any problems. The printer works fine on the subnet.

While I need to be able to connect to the printer across the subnet, contacting the printer from a different subnet is almost secondary. I am more curious in how to troubleshoot this and which device ultimately is responsible for me being unable to contact the printer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance with this data it looks like your Sharp copier is missing the gateway address or has the wrong one set or it's netmask is wrong.

Comment: Thats what I thought as well. I checked it a few times because that made the most sense. But its not- gateway is correct, netmask is correct.

Comment: Do you have access lists on your gateway?

Comment: ETL - I had the wrong default gateway set on the copier! The def gateway setting was buried in the web gui, but when I connected via telnet it jumped out at me! Oh well - good that your pointed it out to me.